# Ruby: Transform two-dimensional array into sorted hash with keys based on the first letter of the first element

Tags: ruby

Say I have the following two-dimensional array (unsorted)

```
[["Abigail", 1047], ["Betty", 1049], ["Alfred", 1048], ["Bernadette", 1050]]
```

How can I transform this into a hash with alphabetical keys based on the first letter of the first element? The key would need to be sorted as well as the array elements, based on their first element (i.e. the person's name in this case):

```
{
'A' => [['Abigail','1047'], ['Alfred','1048']],
'B' => [['Bernadette','1050'], ['Betty','1049']]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = [["Abigail", 1047], ["Betty", 1049], ["Alfred", 1048], ["Bernadette", 1050]]
p Hash[a.sort.chunk{|x| x[0][0]}.to_a]
```

Works for 1.9.x

Comment: I like it! I didn't know `Enumerable#chunk`

Comment: Perfect. Very elegant, didn't know about `chunk`.

Comment: Note that you can unpack the array pair in the chunk: `chunk { |name, n| name[0] }`.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [["Abigail", 1047], ["Betty", 1049], ["Alfred", 1048], ["Bernadette", 1050]]
p a.sort.group_by{|el| el.first[0]}
```

`sort` the array to make sure the keys in the hash are sorted (in 1.9), `group_by` first letter of the first element (the name).

Answer (score 1):

```
names_and_values = [["Abigail", 1047], ["Betty", 1049], ["Alfred", 1048], ["Bernadette", 1050]]
#=> [["Abigail", 1047], ["Betty", 1049], ["Alfred", 1048], ["Bernadette", 1050]]
names_and_values.sort.reduce({}) do |memo, name_and_value|
  name = name_and_value[0]
  initial = name[0]
  ( memo[initial] ||= [] ) << name_and_value
  memo
end
#=> {"A"=>[["Abigail", 1047], ["Alfred", 1048]], "B"=>[["Bernadette", 1050], ["Betty", 1049]]}
```